# Dynamically change annotation value in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

How do I change an annotation value dynamically in Drupal 8? For instance, I would like `cron = {"time" = 120}` in the following annotation to be `cron = {"time" = 600}`. I would like to get 600 or some other value from configuration.

```
/**
 * Updates the google analytics counters.
 *
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "google_analytics_counter_worker",
 *   title = @Translation("Import Data from Google Analytics"),
 *   cron = {"time" = 120}
 * )
 */
```

I've tried adding a constant before the annotation:

```
const DURATION = 600;

/**
 * Updates the google analytics counters.
 *
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "google_analytics_counter_worker",
 *   title = @Translation("Import Data from Google Analytics"),
 *   cron = {"time" = DURATION}
 * )
 */
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant DURATION, class                                                                [error]
Drupal\google_analytics_counter\Plugin\QueueWorker\GoogleAnalyticsCounterQueue. in
/private/var/www/sites/mskcc_deploy/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hook_queue_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_queue_info_alter/8.4.x) for this:

```
function mymodule_queue_info_alter(&$queues) {
  $queues['google_analytics_counter_worker']['cron']['time'] = DURATION;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.